# PWM generating circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, resistors, pwm, filter

I know that the following circuit gives a pwm signal at the output, how can I determine the on-time, off-time and the frequency:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGj5GW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I know that the mathematical relationship between the reference voltage and the duty cycle is nonlinear because the sine wave at the output of the capacitor-input-filter network is not a linear function, but how can find it?

Comment: Kind a weird PWM generator. Nobody will ever use this approach.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Why? I think it is a very interesting one.

Comment: Let the others judge, that's why this forum exists. It's too susceptible to all possible disturbances, it can't deliver a stable frequency, duty ratio, all aspects that you would like to have in a PWM generator, so it's busted, from my point of view, of course.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I need to get the mathematics right (and the physical meaning of that of course)

Comment: First of all the Vref+ and Vref- tags are for power only. Vin changes the 'trip' point, and cannot exceed Vref+ or Vref-. Marko's issue was probably with the feedback circuit R1, L, C1 and C2. You need a RF op-amp for this circuit to work, and 'L' will be sensitive to any metal or your hand. You cannot breadboard such an unstable circuit.